# How to get file name from download link in firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have image view which loads image using Glide using download link. Code is given below :

How can I get the file name stored in fire base storage from the download url ?

```java
Glide.with(ct)
  .load(downloadurllink)
  .centerCrop();

placeholder(R.drawable.common_icon_dark)
  .into(holder.image);
```

Comment: You need to save uploaded file/image url to store realtime database and get from realtime database

Comment: @AnasMehar You have a point!

Comment: @snth Did something help you or not?

Comment: @ Gaur Mall I stored and retrived from database and thanks for your code too.

Answer (score 5):

You can get filename easily using the name property.
Example:

```
val httpsReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/art-                     
track.appspot.com/o/images%2Fu1nffhbfdjsa%2FN11vSOYorUM2%2FImageName.JPG? 
alt=media&token=86081f67-9065-4a13-aa0b-14fab7d44bf3")

Log.d(TAG, "filename: ${httpsReference.name}")
```

Android Example:

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(urlImg);
String link = storageReference.getName();
Toast.makeText(EditAQuestionP1.this, link, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I used a Regular Expression to extract the file name from the download URL

`%2..*%2F(.*?)\?alt`

Eg: If your download URL is `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/art-track.appspot.com/o/images%2Fu1nffdGQ7QPLIMp7N11vSOYorUM2%2FCapture.JPG?alt=media&token=86081f67-9065-4a13-aa0b-14fab7d44bf3` , by using `%2..*%2F(.*?)\?alt` you can extract "Capture.JPG"

Answer (score 3):

If the URL is in this pattern:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/art-track.appspot.com/o/images%2Fu1nffhbfdjsa%2FN11vSOYorUM2%2FImageName.JPG?alt=media&token=86081f67-9065-4a13-aa0b-14fab7d44bf3

then this will work to split the URL into the pattern from 2F till 2F and it will remove the extension (.jpg or .png)

```
String url="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/art-                     
track.appspot.com/o/images%2Fu1nffhbfdjsa%2FN11vSOYorUM2%2FImageName.JPG? 
alt=media&token=86081f67-9065-4a13-aa0b-14fab7d44bf3";

print(url.split(RegExp(r'(%2F)..*(%2F)'))[1].split(".")[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many options. Two of the most used ones are:

**1.** You can use `File Metadata` in Firebase Storage to get the file name from URL. Basically, you create a Firebase Data Reference and then add a file metadata listener, like this:

```
    // Create a storage reference from our app
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

    // Get reference to the file
    StorageReference fileRef = storageRef.child("images/forest.jpg");

    fileRef.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
            String filename = storageMetadata.getName();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        }
    });
```

This code was taken from the documentation which I advice you to check out: [File Metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata)

**2.** Another option is to store your URL with the name in `Firebase Database`. This has the advantage of avoiding unnecessary listeners. That means that you can get the name with a single value event listener without having to load all of the file metadata.

```
    database.child("files").child("url")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              String name = dataSnapShot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    }
```

It depends on your implementation on how you want to do it. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the reference method:

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
let yourFirestoreURL = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/art-track.appspot.com/o/images%2Fu1nffdGQ7QPLIMp7N11vSOYorUM2%2FCapture.JPG?alt=media&token=86081f67-9065-4a13-aa0b-14fab7d44bf3"
let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: yourFirestoreURL)

print(storageRef.name)
```

For further details, see the google guide here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/create-reference

Answer (score 1):

```
var storageReference =
      firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(url);
  String imgName = storageReference.name;
  print(imgName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a file having the url, you can do this:

```
final httpsReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(url);

await FirebaseStorageService.deleteFile(httpsReference.fullPath);
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution for iOS!

```
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"%2F(.*?)\\?alt" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:photo_url options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [photo_url length])];
    if (matches && matches.count > 0) {
        NSString *substringForFirstMatch = [photo_url substringWithRange:[matches[0] rangeAtIndex:1]];
    }
```