# How to get the size of the file stored in firebase storage and its link in realtime database?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

here is my code to get the file size but I am unable to get it.:-

ImageURL is stored in realtime database

```
 Picasso.get().load(ImageURL).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_image_200)
            .into(selected_title_image)


        val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(ImageURL)
        ImageSize = storageReference.getBytes()
        ImageSize /= 1024
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, ImageSize.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

I use the reference of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389428/how-to-get-file-name-from-download-link-in-firebase-storage) to get the size of the file using this question but I failed. I know getBytes() function will not give file size but I don't know what will give?

ImageSize is of type Long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code. You will get the desired results.

```
 val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(ImageURL)

        storageReference.getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener {it->
            ImageSize = it.size.toLong()
            ImageSize /= 1024
        }
```